# PyQt create another main window when pp.Server() is executed when the script is put in exe

Tags: python, pyqt, parallel-processing, exe

I'm working on some little python that aimed to be distributed as standalone application. 
I want to use parallel python as it can helps me to make the execution quite quicker. 
With this following example, when I create an executable via pyinstaller, when it calls `pp.Server()` it launches a new window. When I close the new window a pipe error is raised.

Here is an example of script where this problem occurs :

```
import pp, os, sys, multiprocessing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(188, 119)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        pass

class TestClass(object):
    __slots__ = ('var')
    def __init__(self): 
        self.var = 'a string'
    def doSomething (self, input_string) : 
        self.var = input_string

class PPTask (object) :
    def __init__ (self) :
        pass
    def ppTask(self, file = '') :
        html = open(file).read()
        soup = Soup(html)
        ret_results = []
        for i in xrange(10) : 
            tc = parallel_tests.TestClass()
            s = str(soup.title.string) # if it is not put in string it won't work in multithreading....
            #~ tc.doSomething(soup.title.string) # this doesn't works
            tc.doSomething(s) # this works if s is a string not a "soup string"
            ret_results.append(tc)
        return ret_results

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow) : 
    def __init__ (self, parent = None) :
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.createSignals()
    def createSignals(self): 
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.doItBaby)
    def doItBaby (self) :
        print('it works until here ')
        try : 
            job_server = pp.Server() # this creates a new mainwindow ! 
        except Exception, e : 
            print("I supposed you've just closed the new window created haven't you? " + str(e))
        job_list = []
        results = []
        cmpt = 0
        for i in xrange(100) : 
            pt = PPTask()
            job_list.append(job_server.submit(pt.ppTask, ('anHTMfile.htm',),modules = ("parallel_tests","from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup")))
        for job in job_list : 
            results.append(job())
        for result in results :
            for item in result :
                print 'cmpt = ' + str(cmpt)
                cmpt += 1
                print item.var

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()    
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Window()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I dit try to add freeze_support() but it didn't help as I would expected.

If anyone could help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that parallel python has no official freeze support. Someone else seemed to have the same problem via py2exe:
http://www.parallelpython.com/component/option,com_smf/Itemid,1/topic,161.0/wap2,wap2

Using the multiprocessing freeze would work if you were just using that module but it has no impact on the PP module.

The problem is that it is launching your main app again instead of the worker so you end up seeing another instance of your app. PP uses IPC to communicate, so when you kill the window you kill its communication pipe and PP complains.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tried it, but it probably is because if you close the new window there are no more references to your object and it gets garbage collected. 
it's not very good design anyway having all that stuff happening in the gui.